# Bootstrap - Navbar Active class based on URL

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm trying to figure out how to change a navbar button to be set to class = active if the user is on that page.

I've done some googling but can't find anything that worked for me.

Here's the navbar code in case something here isn't right.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background: #64D6FF; border: 0">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" style="font-size: 20px">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="audio.php">Audio</a></li>
      <li><a href="visual.php>">Visual</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: i know a method simple, just add an ID to the body tag, and create a javascript  to read the body id and if the id its the same to the id of the Audio <li> addClass("active");

Comment: @SampaioLeal if OP has to do that, they might as well add the class manually to the list foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `PHP` get the current file name by using [basename()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_basename.asp) function and compare with the list item, if the current page equals the list item `echo 'class="active"';`

> The basename() function returns the filename from a path.

```
<?php
    $filename = basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"], '.php');
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; background: #64D6FF; border: 0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center" style="font-size: 20px">
            <li <?php echo ($filename == 'home') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li <?php echo ($filename == 'audio') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="audio.php">Audio</a></li>
            <li <?php echo ($filename == 'visual') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="visual.php>">Visual</a></li>
            <li <?php echo ($filename == 'contact') ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked a treat, I can stop tearing my hair out now! Thank You <3